# Kill active process when terminal is closed

Tags: terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm looking to set up my terminal to automatically kill the active process when I close the window. The equivalent of hitting `Ctrl+C` right before closing the window, but automatic.

This is what I have in my `.bashrc` so far:

```
function onExit(){
    xdotool key ctrl+c
}
trap onExit EXIT
```

`trap` is successfully running that function, but `xdotool` (based on a suggestion elsewhere) doesn't kill the active process. Can anyone suggest something else that might work? Or is what I'm trying to do not possible?

EDIT: I'm in Windows Terminal running Ubuntu via WSL2. That's probably pretty important.

Comment: What's your active process?

Comment: On my system this is automatic behaviour and I actively try to prevent hangups using specific commands e.g. `nohup` / `disown`; this thread has some more info on these types of cases: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84737/in-which-cases-is-sighup-not-sent-to-a-job-when-you-log-out

Comment: Just whatever I most recently run. Typically it's node for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a terminal window in Gnome shell or similar, closing a terminal window would usually kill foreground processes, like pressing Ctrl+C does, if possible.
It will kill all child processes of your terminal/bash session.

Please check the top answer here:
https://superuser.com/questions/243460/what-to-do-when-ctrl-c-cant-kill-a-process

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Redhat there is `huponexit` shopt setting that you can change; see https://serverfault.com/questions/115999/if-i-launch-a-background-process-and-then-log-out-will-it-continue-to-run